# Convert literal to Excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have a GridView and a few columns are literal:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Next Service Date">
         <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Literal ID="litNextSvcDate" runat="server">/asp:Literal>
         </ItemTemplate>
```

I want to convert this GridView to an Excel spreadsheet and all the `boundfield` columns display on the spreadsheet but not the literals. Here is the code to convert the Grid to Excel:

```
 protected void ToExcel(GridView grid, string Name, string FileName)
    {
        if (!FileName.Contains(".xls"))
        {
            FileName = FileName + ".xls";
        }
        string style = "<style><!--table@page{mso-header-data:\"&C" + Name + " Date/: &D/ Page &P\"; mso-page-orientation:landscape; mso-page-scale:89;}     br     {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}  --></style>";

        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + "");
        this.EnableViewState = false;
        Response.Write("<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">");
        Response.Write("<head>");
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=windows-1252\">");
        Response.Write("<!--[if gte mso 9]>");
        Response.Write("<xml>");
        Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorkbook>");
        Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheets>");
        Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheet>");
        Response.Write("<x:Name>" + Name + " Table</x:Name>");
        Response.Write("<x:WorksheetOptions>");
        Response.Write("<x:Panes>");
        Response.Write("</x:Panes>");
        Response.Write("<x:Print>");
        Response.Write("<x:ValidPrinterInfo/>");
        Response.Write("<x:Scale>89</x:Scale>");
        Response.Write("</x:Print>");
        Response.Write("</x:WorksheetOptions>");
        Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheet>");
        Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheets>");
        Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorkbook>");
        Response.Write("</xml>");
        Response.Write("<![endif]-->");
        Response.Write("</head>");
        Response.Write("<body>");

        System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);

        List<int> HiddenCols = new List<int>();
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!grid.Columns[i].Visible)
            {
                HiddenCols.Add(i);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            if(HiddenCols.Contains(i))
                grid.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Visible = false;
        }

        ClearControls(grid);



        grid.RenderBeginTag(oHtmlTextWriter);
        grid.HeaderRow.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (HiddenCols.Contains(i))
                    row.Cells[i].Visible = false;
            }
            row.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
        }
        grid.FooterRow.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
        grid.RenderEndTag(oHtmlTextWriter);

        Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());


        Response.Write("</body>");
        Response.Write("</html>");
        Response.End();

    }
```

Comment: can you just use an http handler?

Comment: @DanielA.White could you give an example?